# php memory limit cannot be modified

Tags: php, mysql, memory

I have a php script that loads data from a database.
The table I am loading the data from is 50mb big, and the current php memory settings allow for 128mb - still I get the error message

```
Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 6 bytes)
```

Some research has led me to changing the following in php.ini:

```
memory_limit = 128M
```

I changed it to -1, which according to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/ini.core.php) will set it to infinite. To no avail.

Not only does it not makes sense that even if the query returned all of the 50mb, it should not complain since the limit is set to 128mb - strangely, the query I run does not even need much memory: when I echo it out and run it directly in the database, it only returns three rows. The query looks as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE foreign_id=1
```

Does anyone know how to fix that problem? I would like to set the memory limit to infinite.

### EDIT 1

First of all - does it matter that I run the script from my terminal, not from my browser?

Second, here is the php code:

```
//Connect to database
$user="root";
$databasePassword="password";
$host="127.0.0.1";
$database="primarydata";
$identifier=mysql_connect($host,$user,$databasePassword,true);
$db1=mysql_select_db($database);

//Select * from first table
$query="SELECT id,name,city,country FROM table1 WHERE id>=1 ORDER BY id ASC";
$result=mysql_query($query);
$datas=array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_object($result)) $datas[]=(object) $row;

//Loop through artists
for($i=0;$i<sizeof($datas);$i++){
    for($j=$i+1;$j<sizeof($datas);$j++){
        //This is where the problem occurs
        $query="SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE data_id=".$datas[$i]->id;
    }
}
```

Third, do I have to use "--enable-memory-limit'"?

Comment: This needs more info. Are you on your own server? What does `phpinfo()` show when you change the memory limit - maybe you are editing the wrong php.ini?

Comment: Perhaps you should be using the result instead of the default of storing the result, see `MYSQLI_USE_RESULT` in http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php. This is why it is taking up 50MB for the result set or more, as PHP is loading the entire result set into memory.

Comment: @Pekka I am on my own local server, and I seem to be editing the correct php.ini file. It does change the memory limit in there. Maybe I can do something with "--enable-memory-limit'"?

Comment: @Charles so the php.ini says there is no limit, yet you get the error message above? That's strange.

Comment: it would be helpful if you can show the php code, since there can be a situation which is not related to mysql that is causing the memory issues.. e.g. an endless loop..

Comment: What else do you do inside those nested loops? And how many rows does `SELECT id,name,city,country FROM table1 WHERE id>=1 ORDER BY id ASC` return?

Comment: Solution found - thank you very much!

Comment: Did you restart your web server after making changes to php.ini?

Comment: @AlexLunix Yes I did, but it didn't change things...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
ini_set('memory_limit','-1')
```

When I insert millions of entries into a database (samples), then I had the same problem as you. This one helped.

EDIT: to add, using this is not recommended (only e.g. on localhost for examples as I gave you, entering tons of sample data into a database, etc.) This answer was posted before you posted your php code...

Comment: This should never be used as a fix for a problem! Find the reason why your using too much ram, in this case it is poor design of the script.

Comment: @Geoffrey: that's true! I did not suggest that it was the best solution, I just posted this as the answer to his question, at that time he hasn't had his php code posted... so I don't see your reason for the downvote, sorry...

Comment: @Chris - down-vote is because you did not state that this is not the proper solution to the actual problem and should only be used as a stop-gap measure at best.

Comment: @Geoffrey: added it to the answer to make it clear, so others won't use it for things it is not intended for...

Answer (score 2):

1. Returning objects will use more RAM
2. why not just write one while inside the other.
3. the mysql_* methods are being deprecated, you should use the newer mysqli_* methods.
4. why load your entire first result set into an array?? There is your 100MB, the MySQL client library has already loaded 50MB into its cache, then your caching it again in PHP.

Example:

```
//Select * from first table
$query  = "SELECT id, name, city, country FROM table1 WHERE id >= 1 ORDER BY id ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    //Loop through artists
    $query2  = "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE data_id = " . $row['id'];
    $result2 = mysqli_query($dbc, $query2);
    while($artist = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
        // Do stuff with $row and $artist
    }
}
```